# Can't write to directory C:\inetpub from MS SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, iis

Vendor wants write access to C:\inetpub\ on Windows Server 2016. I run an SQL script to test if it can create files in directory from within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which runs on the same server. I believe we're running IIS 10. When running script, I get access denied.

The vendor required the following users have full control to the directory C:\inetpub\ on WEBPC server:

```
MS SQL server built in user:  NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT
local machine account:        dbTestUser
```

We have added SQLSERVERAGENT and dbTestUser to the folder  C:\inetpub\ with the following security access but we still can't write to it.

Current Security rights:

```
CREATOR OWNER   none
SYSTEM          full control
Test User(WEBPC\dbTestUser)        full control
Administrators(WEBPC\dbTestUser)   full control
Users(WEBPC\Users)                 Read & execute,List contents, read
SQLSERVERAGENT                     full control
TrustedInstaller                   full control
```

I just get Access denied and no description from within MSSMS when i run the sql script.

SQL Code provided by vendor:

```
USE[testData]

DECLARE @Folder nvarchar(max) = 'D:\DBData\Rep6\';
DECLARE @SentFolder nvarchar(max) = 'D:\DBData\Rep6\senders\';
DECLARE @DocumentBlank nvarchar(max) = 'Rep6temp';
DECLARE @IISFileName nvarchar(max) = 'Rep6h';
DECLARE @IISFolder nvarchar(max) = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\';
DECLARE @CMDMTD VARCHAR(4000) = 'COPY "' + @Folder + @DocumentBlank + '.xlsx" "' + @IISFolder + @IISFileName + '.xlsx"';
exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMDMTD
GO
```

Comment: are both the "SQL Server" and "SQL Server Agent" services using that "NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT" account?    Running the code in management studio the account that "SQL Server" service is using  would need access, if running the code via an Agent Job then the account used by "SQL Server Agent" would need access.

Comment: I'd we curious what your script is creating the file.  Care to share?

Comment: I posted the code that tries to copy a blank file to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\

Comment: Any software that requires full access to inetpub is software I would run away from screaming immediately if not sooner. That is a massive security issue. But then again having sql server and IIS on the same box isn't great practice either. As now your sql server is in the DMZ.

Comment: In services, I see: SQL Server Agent(MSSQLSERVER, log on as: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT, the SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) is log on as: NT Service\MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I didn't setup the server. I found out this week that my manager set it up and apparently the vendor is unable to write the files to the directory, so I'm scrambling trying to figure out why. He is on vacation this week.

Comment: What is the IUSR for? Does anyone know. I also see a group called IIS_IUSRS. What is the group for. Will adding that group with full access to c:\inetpub allow it to write to that directory

Comment: For SQL server logins that are member of sysadmin, SQL server uses the service account to access file system. For the accounts are not member of sysadmin role, you need to create a proxy account and SQL server will use that proxy account to access the file system

Comment: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT is a member of the group Administrators. Should I add NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER to that group?

Comment: Tim thanks for the tip. I got it working.

Comment: If their reply is helpful, it is appreciated if you could post and mark their reply as answer. So that this thread would help more people.

Comment: Jalpa, how do you mark the question answered. I don't see where I can mark the question answered.